# On counter-examples to Noether's Problem

Tags: reference-request, invariant-theory, rational-functions

Noether's Problem was introduced by Emmy Noether in [4]:

Let $\mathsf{k}$ be a field and $K=\mathsf{k}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a purely transcendental extension. Let $G<S_n$ be a group acting by permutations on the set of variables, in a transitive fashion. $G$ induces a group of algebra automorphisms of $K$, which for simplicity again will be called $G$. **Noether's Problem** asks: for what finite permutation actions is $K^G$ a purely transcendental extension of $\mathsf{k}$?

Noether introduced the problem due to its connection to the Inverse Galois Problem (see [2]). Many interesting cases of group actions giving positive solution to this problem were discorvered (see [1]).

Eventually, over $\mathbb{Q}$, counter-examples to Noether's Problem were discovered simultaneously by Swan and Vokresenskii ([6],[7]), and then Lenstra (again over $\mathbb{Q})$ [3] classified all abelian groups for which Noether's Problem fails (and discovered that the smallest group that can give a counter-example to Noether's Problem is $C_8$).

Finally, Saltman in [5] gave counter-examples in algebraically closed fields. Being more precise, he constructed an infinite family of $p$-groups that give counter-examples for all algebraically closed fields whose characteristic does not divides $|G|$.

Much more counter-examples were found after that: a recent survey discussing this is [1].

The literature on counter-examples to Noether's Problem is vast, but in all cases I know of, the counter-examples shows not only that $K^G$ is not rational; it is *also* not even stably-rational.

I am very interested in a possible counter-example to Noether's Problem such that $K^G$ is not rational but it *is* stably-rational. Any known reference on this would be greatly appreciated; I will also accept as answers 'folkore' examples.

**References**:

[1] A. Hoshi, "Noether's problem and rationality problem for multiplicative invariant fields: a survey", arXiv:2010.01517.

[2] C. U. Jensen, A. Ledet, N. Yui "Generic Polynomials: Constructive Aspects of the Inverse Galois Problem"

[3] H.W. Lenstra Jr., "Rational functions invariant under a finite abelian group"

[4]     E. Noether, "Gleichungen mit vorgeschriebener Gruppe"

[5] D.J. Saltman, "Noether's problem over an algebraically closed field"

[6] R.G. Swan, "Invariant rational functions and a problem of Steenrod"

[7]     V.E. Voskresenskii, "Algebraic tori"

---

**Bonus historical question**: in older literature on the subject, some author's call Noether's Problem 'Noether's Conjecture', which seems to imply that she belived that her problem would have a positive solution for every group. Unfortunately, I can't read German, and hence I don't know what was the opinion she expressed when she introduced the problem. Does anyone knows if she in fact believed that her problem would have a positive solution for all groups?

Comment: See also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443889/on-noethers-problem